# How to add hours in date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
id  createddate              expirydate
1   2017-08-18 16:22:32.337 
2   2017-08-18 14:16:06.220
3   2017-08-18 14:16:06.220
4   2017-08-17 15:01:56.633
```

I want to add 8 hours to `createddate` to generate the value for `expirydate`.

Example:

```
id  createddate                 expirydate
1   2017-08-18 15:22:32.337     2017-08-18 23:22:32.337
```

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 3):

Use `update` if you actually want to change the data in the base table:

```
update t
    set expirydate = dateadd(hour, 8, createddate);
    where expirydate is null;
```